# Error useNavigation react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hola estoy tratando de usar `useNavigation` para moverme entre pantallas pero me sale un error en el `DetailScreen`, estuve buscando información sobre eso y creo que es porque en la version 6 de react hicieron cambio en el uso del navigation.

import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native'

```
export const HomeScreen = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Home Screen</Text>

            <Button
                title="ir detalle"
                onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('DetailScreen')}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Alguien puede ayudarme brindando información al respecto de eso, estuve buscando en la documentación oficial pero no encontré algo claro. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debería quedar algo así:

```
export const HomeScreen = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigation();
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Home Screen</Text>

            <Button
                title="ir detalle"
                onPress={()=> navigate('/DetailScreen')}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

---

Es correcto que en react-router v6 se presentaron cambios, por ejemplo:

V5 se usa useHistory()

V6 se usa useNavigate()

---

Puedes ver las documentaciones aquí:

V6: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6

V5: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Answer (score 0):

desde react router v6 es asi

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

let navigate = useNavigate()
    
navigate('/pagename')
```

puedes ver mas aca [react router v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview)

Answer (score 0):

podrías usar el Navigate:

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const HomeScreen = () => {

 const handleDetail() => {
  <Navigate to="/DetailScreen" />
 }

 return (
  <View>
   <Text>Home Screen</Text>

   <Button
    title="ir detalle"
    onClick={handleDetail()}
   />
  </View>
 )
}
```